# Django create new record instead of updating

Tags: django, save, overriding

I have the following model

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    FOOBAR_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Moreover, I have created a form that allows me to edit existing instances of FooBar. I would like to update the existing record when foo is changed, but create a new record when bar is changed.

I figured a good way to go would be to override the **save** method, as it would avoid having to do extra queries on the database, which I have done by adding the following to my FooBar model.

```
__original_bar = None

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FooBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__original_bar = self.bar

def save(self, force_insert=False, Force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.bar != self.__original_bar:
            super(FooBar, self).save(force_insert=True, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs)
            self.__original_bar= self.bar
        else:
            super(FooBar, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I update foo everything works fine, but when I update bar the following error is displayed:

> Key ("FOOBAR_ID")=(2) already exists.

I am apparently entirely wrong on what force_insert does. How can I force it to create a new record in save?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your primary key to `None` and Django automatically create new record. You can read more about this in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.bar != self.__original_bar:
        self.FOOBAR_ID = None
        self.__original_bar= self.bar
    super(FooBar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the id when bar is being used. Try to remove it before sending the data to the front end.

What's happening is that you are trying to add a new row to the database with a primary key "Key ("FOOBAR_ID")=(2)" which already exists.